# Test Class Not Covering Execute Method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Batch Class not covering execute method

```
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact__c> scope) {

    Map<Id,Account> contactIdWithacc = new Map<Id,Account>();       

    for(Account  acc : scope) {
       if(acc.Contact__c.size() == 0) {
         contactIdWithacc.put(acc.Resource__c, acc); 
       }                                                
    }

    String sd = Date.Today().addDays(-6).format();
    String ed = Date.Today().format();
    Account_Uitility.Contact('Demo_Test_App', contactIdWithacc, sd, ed);
    }
```

Test Class Method

```
    static testmethod void test() {        
    Test.startTest();
    Account_Batch trb = new Account_Batch ();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(trb);
    Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: You also have to create the data as per the query in your start method.

Comment: ... as otherwise the `start` method returns zero rows so that the `execute` method is never called.

Comment: You don't have any assertions. A unit test this is not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create Account and Contact records in the test class before triggering the batch class. My inference is based on your execute method code.

Best practice would be use a test data generator class to load data from single class. You can also use test setup method in your test class to re-use the same test data for testing multiple methods.